# Plymouth failed at boot - CAUGHT SEGV

Tags: systemd, plymouth

I have a degraded systemd on my Raspberry (Raspberry OS) and the culprit is :  plymouth. I have this error (catch SEGV)

```
plymouth-start.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit plymouth-start.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'killed' and its exit status is 11.
```

How can I repair this? I saw in logs to change Kill from none to mixed but that doesn't solve the issue. I can do clear-failed but that does not solve the issue.

Comment: Plymouth isn't a hard requirement of anything AFAIK, so you could just `systemctl mask plymouth`.

Comment: Great I was wondering because of Ubuntu, it seems kinda essential... Thanks, if I don't have any solutions, I'II do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SEGV` is a typical outcome of a software bug. If you're building the SW yourself, you may want to run it under `valgrind` to get more information about the function causing it.

If you're just a user, reinstall the SW, and make sure you use only compatible packages. Ideally you should install everything with `apt`, without touching `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If you need extra packages, make sure they are actually supported on the latest Pi OS. E.g. blindly following a tutorial from 5-10 years ago may still refer to packages for Debian Wheezy/Jessie, and that's exactly what will cause a segmentation violation down the road.

Comment: All comes from apt but I needed some new versions for some softwares from testing and therefore the dependancies. Do you think it is the cause? Should I upgrade everything to testing? Maybe I fall into the broken mix testing-stable… however priority is massively on stable. However the machine is still running (on headless mode). I did not try directly.

Comment: That's really a separate question, but pretty sure if you just add the testing repo to `sources.list` you should then get multiple version options when using `apt` etc.

Comment: Testing repo is added on source but the priority is lower so I only downloaded from testing using apt -t testing. But my only question is: does this mix make plymouth failed or not? Is it risky to update it to testing and see how it works?

Comment: @JoelCrypto As the name "testing" suggests, packages from that repo could be broken in various ways. I'm not saying this is necessarily the reason for the bug, but it could be. Upgrading everything to testing might fix the issue, or bring several new ones. Worth a try if you have a backup.

Comment: Okay so I have just uploaded this service to testing (7 new packages) and now everything in systemd is clean. I have a better mix testing-stable now (lol). Thanks everyone.